# Safari css wrong element height

Tags: javascript, css, safari, opencart, caroufredsel

I have a problem with wrong calculated height of few elements. This occurs only in Safari browser.
Element:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
```

Can be changed to normal visibility after page refresh. And:

```
<div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" ...
```

http://94.154.222.6:81/zhenskaya-odezhda-optom/23187-zhenskaya-bluza-pronto-moda-8133-seryj-1499-zhenskaya

If first element is showing correctly it will be showing correctly further. There is one trick for displaying the bug again. Turn off images showing in Safari developer menu, refresh page and turn on image showing.

Kindly ask to help. Thanks in advance.